# Не работает скрипт php через .html файл OpenServer

Tags: php, html, apache, openserver

Пример с ресурса. Форма с данными. При нажатии на кнопку должны выводиться введенные данные.

Когда нажимаю на кнопку, редиректит на пустую страницу `http://*название домена*/check.php`

В конфиг файле apache добавила `.html .htm` к `AddType         application/x-httpd-php .php    .php5 .phtml`

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="check.php" method="POST">
        <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
        <p> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname"></p>
        <p> E-mail: <input type="text" name=""email></p>
        <p> Message: <br><textarea name="message" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea></p>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

check.php:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['request_method'] === 'POST'){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        echo $name."<br />".$surname."<br />".$email."<br />".$message."<br />";
    }
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .shtml .htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из кода вижу минимум две ошибки:

1. $_SERVER['request_method'] - названия глобальных переменных пишутся в upper case, т.е. REQUEST_METHOD
2. Ошибка при заполнении emails: `<p> E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"></p>`

Вот в таком виде у меня сработало, но не проверял настройки вашего веб сервера. Я запускал на встроенном `php -S localhost:9000 -t ./`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:9000/check.php" method="POST">
    <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p> Surname: <input type="text" name="surname"></p>
    <p> E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p> Message: <br><textarea name="message" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea></p>
    <p> <input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    echo $name."<br />".$surname."<br />".$email."<br />".$message."<br />";
}

echo 'OK';

?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду внимательней писать)